# Consultas de registros no banco através de data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gerenciamento de vendas em Ruby com Rails e o cliente precisa consultar as vendas através de datas de dois calendários, que juntos compõem o intervalo de dados que ele quer que sejam puxados do banco.

A parte gráfica e funcional está sendo aplicada por meio de um helper de data: **<%= select_date(Time.now) %>**

Meu problema é fazer com que esse helper realmente interfira na tabela que vão aparecer os dados, trazendo do banco somente os resultados que estão dentro do intervalo selecionado pelo usuário.

Para que esse **<%= select_date(Time.now) %>** converse com as colunas de datas do meu banco, o que eu teria que adicionar ao meu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a gem [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)

**Em seu controller:**

```
def index
  @q = Person.ransack(params[:q])
  @people = @q.result
end
```

**Em sua view:**

```
<%= search_form_for(@q) do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :data_gteq %>
  <%= f.date_field :data_lteq %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```